# Why are voltage and current inversely proportional to power, but directly proportional to resistance?

Tags: ohms-law

Ohm's Law gives the relationship of voltage and current as follows:

$$V = \frac {P}{I}$$
$$V = I \times R$$

In the first equation, voltage and current are inversely proportional.

In the second equation, voltage and current are directly proportional.

If I raise the voltage, am I decreasing the current according to \$V = \frac {P}{I} \$ or am I increasing the current according to \$V = I \times R\$?

Comment: If you raise the voltage, you must decrease the current if you expect to have the same amount of power. In order to decrease the current, you must increase R. Not only that, you must decrease the current even as the voltage increases so you must increase R faster than you increase V. If you just increase V at the same rate you increase R, you get more power due to I^2*R

Comment: Ohm's Law has nothing to do with power. P = VI is sometimes called *Watt's Law*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key issue here is that you are attempting to draw incorrect conclusions from a mixture of Ohms' law and relationships based on but not a direct part of Ohm's law.
Essentially - your question does not make sense as you are mixing items which cannot be directly compared.

I can smell apples.
I can count apples.
I can observe an apple's colour.
I cannot "smell the colour nine"  (in two ways)

V = P/I
can be rearranged as
P = VI
There is NO part of Ohm's law which expresses VI in terms of the other component R .
You have introduced a new factor, P, and are attempting to now make V, I and R obey relationships relative to it which are not fundamental to each other.

Ohm's law can be rearranged in 3 ways:
V = IR
R = V/I
I = V/R

Any relationships between these three parameters are expressed by Ohm's law. Add some other factor and the relevant relationships are what they are.

Some thinking will show the Power may be expressed as
P = VI  or
P = V^2/R  or
P = I^2.R

ie  Power
is proportional to I & R if V is a "free" variable.
Is proportional to V^2 and inversely proportional to R if I is a free variable
Is proportional to I squared and to R if V is a "free" variable.

in each of the above examples the "free" variable takes on the appropriate value set by Ohms law.

By trying to directly equate the behaviour of current in your two equations you are attempting to demand that Ohm's law be violated.
In V = I x R you see the direct expression of Ohm's law.
In V= P/I -> P = V.I you have R as a "free variable" with it's value set by Ohm's law.

Comment: P = IR ????????

Comment: @DKNguyen  Hmmm. A typo in there somewhere? :-). Thanks - I'll check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the time you took to pin point exactly what it is in my thinking that was flawed.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing apples and oranges. Your first equation deals with power and is independent of Ohm's law. Your second equation is one expression of Ohm's law which says that some materials exhibit an electrical resistance whose magnitude is independent of the value of the current. If power is a constant, then, yes, current and voltage are inversely proportional since power is their product. Again, this has nothing to do with Ohm's Law. Ohm's law says that voltage and current are proportional because resistance is constant. This fact, however, has nothing to do with constant power.

Comment: We were answering in parallel. Our answers essentially match, as you'd expect. Mine has maybe too many words :-).

Comment: Thank you for the response, Barry. You and Russell have answered my question. I've been confused about this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked was in mind too, but I tried to practically solve it and I got the satisfiable answer (at least, to me), but I am not sure if it is right or not. If it is wrong then please do tell!

First, let's recall the meaning of power, voltage, and current in terms of joules, charges, and seconds.

Power = voltage (joules/charge) * current (charges/second)

Canceling charges in voltage and current, power comes out in joules/second.

So, for example, if a source provides a power of 10 watts, i.e., 10 joules/second, and you are using 20 volts, i.e., 20 joules/charge, then to get 20 joules, it will take 2 seconds,
so eventually the speed of current will be half of its actual speed. And the more you increase voltage, the more time it will take if power is constant.

Comment: Good answer. Note that SI units named after a person have their symbols capitalised but are lowercase when spelt out. e.g. V / volt, A / ampere, J / joule, W / watt, etc.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for this information, I have edited my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is caused of a misconception, it is a good question as it does attack the fundamentals.

To address the misconception, electric power is different to the constant of proportionality referred in Ohm's law.

> Ohm's law states that the current through a conductor between two pointsis directly proportional to the voltage across the two points.

\$I \propto V\$, but electric power is defined as the product of voltage and current. \$P = VI ~\Rightarrow ~ I = \frac{P}{V}\$

Here, current is inversely proportional to voltage.

Let's analyse whether we are well familiar with voltage and current in the first place.

- Voltage (V) is the required energy per charge of transfer in circuit.
- Current (I) is the rate of transfer of charge in the circuit.

Hence, electric power [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power) is **logically plausible** here.
It is the rate of transfer of energy.
We scaled the energy spent per charge to the amount of charge transferred over time.
$$P = \frac{E}{q} \cdot \frac{q}{t} = VI$$

About Ohm's law [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), it was **empirical**. Ohm's law often breaks for non-linear resistances, but the statement of proportionality still upholds.
Think in a given simple circuit, increasing the voltage will definitely affect the current positively.

In the two circuits below, power has been increased in the latter one, keeping the resistance same.

## Before

$$Power = 10 W$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIHIFP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

## After

$$Power = 1000 W$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR0mLY.png)</sup>